# LaTeX command that defines two new commands, one as a capitalized version of the other

Tags: macros, math-operators, capitalization

I wish to create a command that defines two new math operators, one being a capitalized version of the other. For example, the command `\makeoperator{log}` would create `\log` and `\Log` to typeset lowercase and uppercase logs. So far, I have the following (first part credit to egreg):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Capitalize}[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \edef\@tempb{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@cdr\@tempa\@nil}%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\@tempb}}%
  \@namedef{\@tempb\@tempa}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}}
\makeatother

\def\makeoperator#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\operatorname{#1}}%
    \Capitalize{\csname #1\endcsname}%
}
```

but this produces an undefined control sequence error. What is wrong?

Comment: as egreg just posted you should void edef completely now but your error was that you should pass `\log` to `\Capitalize` so last line should be `\expandafter\Capitalize\csname #1\endcsname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer TeX primitive commands instead of Expl3 commands (similar to me) then yo can do:

```
\def\DeclareDoubleMathOperator#1{\ddmoA#1\end}
\def\ddmoA#1#2\end{\uppercase{\ddmoB#1}#1{#2}}
\def\ddmoB#1#2#3{%
   \expandafter\def\csname #1#3\endcsname{\mathop{\rm#1#3}\nolimits}%
   \expandafter\def\csname #2#3\endcsname{\mathop{\rm#2#3}\nolimits}%
}

\DeclareDoubleMathOperator{log}
\DeclareDoubleMathOperator{blob}

$\log x+\Log x$

$\blob x+\Blob x$

\bye
```

Comment: This is great! I actually do prefer TeX primitives over expl3 syntax, it just looks nicer to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are better methods, nowadays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareDoubleMathOperator}{m}
 {
  % lowercase version
  \cs_if_exist:cF { #1 }
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathOperator{#1}{#1}
   }
  % capitalized version
  \cs_if_exist:cF { \text_titlecase:n { #1 } }
   {
    \exp_args:Ncx \DeclareMathOperator{ \text_titlecase:n { #1 } } { \text_titlecase:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareDoubleMathOperator{log}
\DeclareDoubleMathOperator{blob}

\begin{document}

$\log x+\Log x$

$\blob x+\Blob x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I'd avoid it. Just define the operators you need.